# How to tell SQLAlchemy what type is in variable "x"

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psql, jsonb

I want to execute a query like this:

```
database.execute(
            "UPDATE examples SET x = :x WHERE id = :example_id",
            {
                'x': x,
                'example_id': example_id
            }
```

In the model, "x" is declared a field of type "JSON". The hstore and array are being formed when this query is executed, but I need to avoid that. I don't understand how to tell SQLAlchemy what type is in the "x" variable. How to translate a request into JSONB processing?

Answer (score 1):

Everything turned out to be easier than I thought. It was necessary to convert the dictionary into a "json" by means of the command: `json.dumps(x)`. After that, everything worked out correctly.